# Response from fetch API in parent component being passed to child component is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a page containing a navigation bar and a table. I want to be able to click a button on the navigation bar and that would trigger a fetch API call. A GET request will be sent to a back-end server and the response received which is passed to the table. Using the response, the table is rendered.

My component structure is as follows:

You have the main component that contains the three components
1. Add Person button
2. View Table button
3. Table

This is the function that is called when I click the 'View Table' button: -

```
sendGETRequest() {
        fetch("http://"+ theIP + ":"+ thePort + "/person", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                        PData: response
                });
        });
}
```

This is the code in the render() function for the 'View Table' button: -

```
<input
 type="button"
 className="btn mainButtonFont mainButtonStyle"
 id="mainButton"
 value="VIEW TABLE"
 onClick={this.sendGETRequest}
/>
```

This is where I'm passing the state to the table component.

```
<Route
  path="/ViewTable"
  render={() => <Table PData={this.state.PData} />}
/>
```

In the table component, in the render() function, I've added this -

```
this.setState({
  personData :  this.props.PData
        });
```

Later there is a map() function that runs which then generates the table.

This code is giving me an error. I get: -

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you init your personData with []?? if not it's the issue.

Comment: @aminmohammadi I do initialise it with []

Comment: Provide a codesandbox link if it's possible to help you resolve this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you data array is inside `response` object against some key like `data` etc. so log your response and see if you are doing something wrong or not.

Always write safe code especially in this scenario where you know that your data will come later. Api can be broken at sometimes so write code in such a way that it should not break.
So where you are using `personData.map()`, do this

```
(personData || []).map()
```

Or if you can use latest features using some babel plugins then

```
personData?.map()
```

Comment: I'd actually removed the console.log part because I thought it might be unnecessary to include it here.The problem that I'm experiencing is that the parent component's state that I'm passing to the child, while readable in the parent component, is 'undefined' in the child component